# grep not resulting specific word if space is present

Tags: shell

Please solve this problem and help me.

I have a file with contents as given below

> #AuthName
>   AuthName

If I grep with the following command,

`grep "^#AuthName$" <filename>`

It will result,

`#AuthName`

But,
If I modified the content with a space in front of `#AuthName` like given below,

> #AuthName
>   AuthName

It wont give any output with the same grep command.The issue is might be because of that space.How to solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The carat in your grep string means beginning of line. Therefore, it'll only return content where "#AuthName" is at the beginning of the line. Take the carat out:

```
grep "#AuthName" <filename>
```

Furthermore, the dollar sign means end of line, so it'll be matching only instances where #AuthName both begins and ends a line.

Comment: But if give `grep "AuthName" <filename>`, It sould output only the second line.My goal is to fetch the specefic word from a file content.Thats why i had put ^ and $ signs before and after the #AuthName respectively.It will work fine if no space before #AuthName.

Answer (score 1):

You could put an optional space(s) there.

```
grep "^ *#AuthName$"
```

Comment: There was a typo in the original (`@` instead of `#`). Fixed.